# Definition of "data-directed programming"

Tags: reference-request

[Section 2.4.3](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%_sec_2.4.3) of [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) provides an example of  *data-directed programing* in the context of dispatching on type, but I didn't find a general definition of what it is.  Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-directed_programming) says that it is a programming technique mentioned in SICP and seems to claim that it is the same as polymorphism.  I am not convinced however that "data-directed programing" could be a reasonable way to call polymorphism.

The following looks to me intuitively like a reasonable definition of *data-directed programming*:

> extensive use of data structures to direct the control flow of the program.

For example, in Python there is [no `case` or `switch` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3103/#rejection-notice), and one [suggested](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python) work-around is to use dictionaries.  This looks to me like an example of data-directed programming.

Is my understanding correct?  If not, what would be the correct general definition?  I would like to see any references.

Comment: If I recall correctly, data-directed programming entails manually programming a lookup table in function of the arguments' types. Polymorphism and method overloading are the "automated" (i.e., as language builtins) way of doing this in "classic" OOP languages (e.g, Java). Python only supports polymorphism, hence you need dictionaries.